# How can I change text color and font of the text produced by my Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

[image]

This is code for a spinning wheel. When a person clicks the spinning wheel, it rotates and gives a result after a few seconds (depending on the script's time settings). How can an edit the color of the below text? So, when the wheel stops, the result text font color must be red on black background. Which part of the code has the reference to this?

```js
(function($) {
  var venues = [{
    "name": "1900 Mexican Grill",
    "type": "Mexican"
  }, {
    "name": "300 East",
    "type": "American/Upscale"
  }, {
    "name": "Angry Ale's",
    "type": "American/Pub "
  }, {
    "name": "Azteca",
    "type": "Mexican"
  }, {
    "name": "Bedder Bedder and Moore",
    "type": "Sandwiches, Salads, Soups"
  }, {
    "name": "Boading",
    "type": "Chinese"
  }, {
    "name": "Brazwell's Premium Pub",
    "type": "American/Pub "
  }, {
    "name": "Brio Tuscan Grille",
    "type": "Italian"
  }, {
    "name": "Brixx",
    "type": "Pizza/Salads"
  }, {
    "name": "Café at 6100",
    "type": "Home Cooking"
  }, {
    "name": "California Pizza Kitchen",
    "type": "Pizza/Salads"
  }, {
    "name": "Chick-Fil-A",
    "type": "Fast Food"
  }, {
    "name": "City Tavern",
    "type": "American/Upscale"
  }, {
    "name": "Copper",
    "type": "Indian"
  }, {
    "name": "Cowfish",
    "type": "Sushi"
  }, {
    "name": "Duckworth's",
    "type": "American/Pub "
  }, {
    "name": "Eddie's Place",
    "type": "American/Pub "
  }, {
    "name": "El Camino",
    "type": "Mexican"
  }, {
    "name": "Fairview Plaza Restaurant",
    "type": "Home Cooking"
  }, {
    "name": "Firebird's Wood Fired Grill",
    "type": "American/Upscale"
  }, {
    "name": "Firehouse Subs",
    "type": "Sandwiches, Salads, Soups"
  }, {
    "name": "Flying Biscuit",
    "type": "American/Fast"
  }, {
    "name": "Fuel",
    "type": "Pizza"
  }, {
    "name": "Good Food on Montford",
    "type": "American/Upscale"
  }, {
    "name": "Harper's Restaurant",
    "type": "American/Upscale"
  }, {
    "name": "Hawthorne's Pizza",
    "type": "Pizza/Italian"
  }, {
    "name": "Luisa's Brick Oven Pizza",
    "type": "Pizza/Italian"
  }, {
    "name": "Maverick Rock Taco",
    "type": "Mexican"
  }, {
    "name": "McAllister's",
    "type": "Sandwiches, Salads, Soups"
  }, {
    "name": "Mellow Mushroom",
    "type": "Pizza/Salads"
  }, {
    "name": "Moe's",
    "type": "Mexican"
  }, {
    "name": "Moosehead Grill",
    "type": "American/Pub "
  }, {
    "name": "Paco's Tacos and Tequila",
    "type": "Mexican"
  }, {
    "name": "Panera ",
    "type": "Sandwiches, Salads, Soups"
  }, {
    "name": "PF Chang's",
    "type": "Chinese"
  }, {
    "name": "Portofinos",
    "type": "Pizza/Italian"
  }, {
    "name": "Qdoba",
    "type": "Mexican"
  }, {
    "name": "Rooster's Wood Fire Kitchen",
    "type": "American/Upscale"
  }, {
    "name": "Rusty's Deli",
    "type": "Sandwiches, Salads, Soups"
  }, {
    "name": "Taco Bell",
    "type": "Fast Food"
  }, {
    "name": "Taco Mac",
    "type": "American/Pub "
  }, {
    "name": "Terrace Café",
    "type": "American/Upscale"
  }, {
    "name": "The Roasting Company",
    "type": "American/Fast"
  }, {
    "name": "Village Tavern",
    "type": "American/Upscale"
  }, {
    "name": "Which Witch?",
    "type": "Sandwiches, Salads, Soups"
  }, {
    "name": "Zack's Hamburgers",
    "type": "American/Fast"
  }];

  // Helpers
  var blackHex = '#333',
    whiteHex = '#fff',
    shuffle = function(o) {
      for (var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x)
      ;
      return o;
    },
    halfPI = Math.PI / 2,
    doublePI = Math.PI * 2;

  String.prototype.hashCode = function() {
    // See http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html        
    var hash = 5381,
      i;
    for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
      char = this.charCodeAt(i);
      hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + char;
      hash = hash & hash; // Convert to 32bit integer
    }
    return hash;
  };

  Number.prototype.mod = function(n) {
    return ((this % n) + n) % n;
  };

  // WHEEL!
  var wheel = {
    timerHandle: 0,
    timerDelay: 33,

    angleCurrent: 0,
    angleDelta: 0,

    size: 290,

    canvasContext: null,

    colors: ['#003366', '#FF6600', '#CCCC00', '#006600', '#3333CC', '#CC0066', '#FF3300', '#009900', '#6600CC', '#33CC33', '#0066CC', '#FF0066', '#3300FF', '#00CC00', '#FFCC00'],

    segments: [],

    seg_colors: [], // Cache of segments to colors

    maxSpeed: Math.PI / 16,

    upTime: 1000, // How long to spin up for (in ms)
    downTime: 5000, // How long to slow down for (in ms)

    spinStart: 0,

    frames: 0,

    centerX: 300,
    centerY: 300,

    spin: function() {
      // Start the wheel only if it's not already spinning
      if (wheel.timerHandle == 0) {
        wheel.spinStart = new Date().getTime();
        wheel.maxSpeed = Math.PI / (16 + Math.random()); // Randomly vary how hard the spin is
        wheel.frames = 0;
        wheel.sound.play();

        wheel.timerHandle = setInterval(wheel.onTimerTick, wheel.timerDelay);
      }
    },

    onTimerTick: function() {
      var duration = (new Date().getTime() - wheel.spinStart),
        progress = 0,
        finished = false;

      wheel.frames++;
      wheel.draw();

      if (duration < wheel.upTime) {
        progress = duration / wheel.upTime;
        wheel.angleDelta = wheel.maxSpeed *
          Math.sin(progress * halfPI);
      } else {
        progress = duration / wheel.downTime;
        wheel.angleDelta = wheel.maxSpeed *
          Math.sin(progress * halfPI + halfPI);
        if (progress >= 1) {
          finished = true;
        }
      }

      wheel.angleCurrent += wheel.angleDelta;
      while (wheel.angleCurrent >= doublePI) {
        // Keep the angle in a reasonable range
        wheel.angleCurrent -= doublePI;
      }
      if (finished) {
        clearInterval(wheel.timerHandle);
        wheel.timerHandle = 0;
        wheel.angleDelta = 0;

        if (console) {
          console.log((wheel.frames / duration * 1000) + " FPS");
        }
      }

      /*
      // Display RPM
      var rpm = (wheel.angleDelta * (1000 / wheel.timerDelay) * 60) / (Math.PI * 2);
      $("#counter").html( Math.round(rpm) + " RPM" );
       */
    },

    init: function(optionList) {
      try {
        wheel.initWheel();
        wheel.initAudio();
        wheel.initCanvas();
        wheel.draw();

        $.extend(wheel, optionList);

      } catch (exceptionData) {
        alert('Wheel is not loaded ' + exceptionData);
      }

    },

    initAudio: function() {
      var sound = document.createElement('audio');
      sound.setAttribute('src', 'wheel.mp3');
      wheel.sound = sound;
    },

    initCanvas: function() {
      var canvas = $('#canvas')[0];
      canvas.addEventListener("click", wheel.spin, false);
      wheel.canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");
    },

    initWheel: function() {
      shuffle(wheel.colors);
    },

    // Called when segments have changed
    update: function() {
      // Ensure we start mid way on a item
      //var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * wheel.segments.length);
      var r = 0,
        segments = wheel.segments,
        len = segments.length,
        colors = wheel.colors,
        colorLen = colors.length,
        seg_color = [], // Generate a color cache (so we have consistant coloring)
        i
      wheel.angleCurrent = ((r + 0.5) / wheel.segments.length) * doublePI;

      for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        seg_color.push(colors[segments[i].hashCode().mod(colorLen)]);
      }
      wheel.seg_color = seg_color;

      wheel.draw();
    },

    draw: function() {
      wheel.clear();
      wheel.drawWheel();
      wheel.drawNeedle();
    },

    clear: function() {
      wheel.canvasContext.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 800);
    },

    drawNeedle: function() {
      var ctx = wheel.canvasContext,
        centerX = wheel.centerX,
        centerY = wheel.centerY,
        size = wheel.size,
        i,
        centerSize = centerX + size,
        len = wheel.segments.length,
        winner;

      ctx.lineWidth = 2;
      ctx.strokeStyle = blackHex;
      ctx.fillStyle = whiteHex;

      ctx.beginPath();

      ctx.moveTo(centerSize - 10, centerY);
      ctx.lineTo(centerSize + 10, centerY - 10);
      ctx.lineTo(centerSize + 10, centerY + 10);
      ctx.closePath();

      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.fill();

      // Which segment is being pointed to?
      i = len - Math.floor((wheel.angleCurrent / doublePI) * len) - 1;

      // Now draw the winning name
      ctx.textAlign = "left";
      ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
      ctx.fillStyle = blackHex;
      ctx.font = "2em Arial";
      winner = wheel.segments[i] || 'Choose at least 1 Venue';
      ctx.fillText(winner, centerSize + 20, centerY);
    },

    drawSegment: function(key, lastAngle, angle) {
      var ctx = wheel.canvasContext,
        centerX = wheel.centerX,
        centerY = wheel.centerY,
        size = wheel.size,
        colors = wheel.seg_color,
        value = wheel.segments[key];

      //ctx.save();
      ctx.beginPath();

      // Start in the centre
      ctx.moveTo(centerX, centerY);
      ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, size, lastAngle, angle, false); // Draw an arc around the edge
      ctx.lineTo(centerX, centerY); // Now draw a line back to the center

      // Clip anything that follows to this area
      //ctx.clip(); // It would be best to clip, but we can double performance without it
      ctx.closePath();

      ctx.fillStyle = colors[key];
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();

      // Now draw the text
      ctx.save(); // The save ensures this works on Android devices
      ctx.translate(centerX, centerY);
      ctx.rotate((lastAngle + angle) / 2);

      ctx.fillStyle = whiteHex;
      ctx.fillText(value.substr(0, 20), size - 15, 0);
      ctx.restore();
    },

    drawWheel: function() {
      var ctx = wheel.canvasContext,
        angleCurrent = wheel.angleCurrent,
        lastAngle = angleCurrent,
        len = wheel.segments.length,
        centerX = wheel.centerX,
        centerY = wheel.centerY,
        size = wheel.size,
        angle,
        i;

      ctx.lineWidth = 1;
      ctx.strokeStyle = blackHex;
      ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
      ctx.textAlign = "right";
      ctx.font = "1em Arial";

      for (i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
        angle = doublePI * (i / len) + angleCurrent;
        wheel.drawSegment(i - 1, lastAngle, angle);
        lastAngle = angle;
      }

      // Draw a center circle
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, 20, 0, doublePI, false);
      ctx.closePath();

      ctx.fillStyle = whiteHex;
      //ctx.strokeStyle = blackHex;
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();

      // Draw outer circle
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, size, 0, doublePI, false);
      ctx.closePath();

      ctx.lineWidth = 10;
      //ctx.strokeStyle = blackHex;
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  };
  $(function() {
    var $venues = $('#venues'),
      $venueName = $('#name'),
      $venueType = $('#types'),
      venueTypes = [],
      $list = $('<ul/>'),
      $types = $('<ul/>'),
      $filterToggler = $('#filterToggle'),
      arrayUnique = function(a) {
        return a.reduce(function(p, c) {
          if (p.indexOf(c) < 0) {
            p.push(c);
          }
          return p;
        }, []);
      };

    $.each(venues, function(index, venue) {
      $list.append(
        $("<li/>")
        .append(
          $("<input />").attr({
            id: 'venue-' + index,
            name: venue.name,
            value: venue.name,
            type: 'checkbox',
            checked: true
          })
          .change(function() {
            var cbox = this,
              segments = wheel.segments,
              i = segments.indexOf(cbox.value);

            if (cbox.checked && i === -1) {
              segments.push(cbox.value);
            } else if (!cbox.checked && i !== -1) {
              segments.splice(i, 1);
            }

            segments.sort();
            wheel.update();
          })

        ).append(
          $('<label />').attr({
            'for': 'venue-' + index
          })
          .text(venue.name)
        )
      );
      venueTypes.push(venue.type);
    });
    $.each(arrayUnique(venueTypes), function(index, venue) {
      $types.append(
        $("<li/>")
        .append(
          $("<input />").attr({
            id: 'venue-type-' + index,
            name: venue,
            value: venue,
            type: 'checkbox',
            checked: true
          })
          .change(function() {
            var $this = $(this),
              i;
            for (i = 0; i < venues.length; i++) {
              if (venues[i].type === $this.val()) {
                $('[name="' + venues[i].name + '"]').prop("checked", $this.prop('checked')).trigger('change');
              }
            }
          })

        ).append(
          $('<label />').attr({
            'for': 'venue-' + index
          })
          .text(venue)
        )
      )
    });

    $venueName.append($list);
    $venueType.append($types);
    // Uses the tinysort plugin, but our array is sorted for now.
    //$list.find('>li').tsort("input", {attr: "value"});

    wheel.init();

    $.each($venueName.find('ul input:checked'), function(key, cbox) {
      wheel.segments.push(cbox.value);
    });

    wheel.update();
    $venues.slideUp().data("open", false);
    $filterToggler.on("click", function() {
      if ($venues.data("open")) {
        $venues.slideUp().data("open", false);
      } else {
        $venues.slideDown().data("open", true);
      }
    });

    $('.checkAll').on("click", function() {
      $(this).parent().next('div').find('input').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked')).trigger("change");
    });
  });
}(jQuery));
```

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #666;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 2;
}

input[type='checkbox']+label {
  padding-left: .5em;
}

label,
#filterToggle {
  display: inline-block;
}

#venues,
#filterToggle {
  background: #fefefe;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #efefef;
}

#venues {
  padding: .5em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#venues ul,
#venues h2 {
  clear: both;
}

#venues li {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  line-height: 1.5;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#filterToggle {
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: .5em;
  margin-top: -1px;
  padding: .5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="venues">
  <h1>Venues <input type="checkbox" class="checkAll" checked /></h1>
  <div id="name"></div>
  <h2>Types <input type="checkbox" class="checkAll" checked /></h2>
  <div id="types"></div>
</div>
<div id="filterToggle">. . .</div>
<div id="wheel">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="600"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="counter"></div>
```

How can I change text color and font of the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can help you with the font size and the color:

```js
          // Now draw the winning name
          ctx.textAlign = "left";
          ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
          ctx.fillStyle = '#fff000'; // text color
          ctx.font = "5em Arial"; // font size and family
```

You have to edit this part.

```js
(function($) {
  var venues = [{
    "name": "1900 Mexican Grill",
    "type": "Mexican"
  }, {
    "name": "300 East",
    "type": "American/Upscale"
  }, {
    "name": "Angry Ale's",
    "type": "American/Pub "
  }, {
    "name": "Azteca",
    "type": "Mexican"
  }, {
    "name": "Bedder Bedder and Moore",
    "type": "Sandwiches, Salads, Soups"
  }, {
    "name": "Boading",
    "type": "Chinese"
  }, {
    "name": "Brazwell's Premium Pub",
    "type": "American/Pub "
  }, {
    "name": "Brio Tuscan Grille",
    "type": "Italian"
  }, {
    "name": "Brixx",
    "type": "Pizza/Salads"
  }, {
    "name": "Café at 6100",
    "type": "Home Cooking"
  }, {
    "name": "California Pizza Kitchen",
    "type": "Pizza/Salads"
  }, {
    "name": "Chick-Fil-A",
    "type": "Fast Food"
  }, {
    "name": "City Tavern",
    "type": "American/Upscale"
  }, {
    "name": "Copper",
    "type": "Indian"
  }, {
    "name": "Cowfish",
    "type": "Sushi"
  }, {
    "name": "Duckworth's",
    "type": "American/Pub "
  }, {
    "name": "Eddie's Place",
    "type": "American/Pub "
  }, {
    "name": "El Camino",
    "type": "Mexican"
  }, {
    "name": "Fairview Plaza Restaurant",
    "type": "Home Cooking"
  }, {
    "name": "Firebird's Wood Fired Grill",
    "type": "American/Upscale"
  }, {
    "name": "Firehouse Subs",
    "type": "Sandwiches, Salads, Soups"
  }, {
    "name": "Flying Biscuit",
    "type": "American/Fast"
  }, {
    "name": "Fuel",
    "type": "Pizza"
  }, {
    "name": "Good Food on Montford",
    "type": "American/Upscale"
  }, {
    "name": "Harper's Restaurant",
    "type": "American/Upscale"
  }, {
    "name": "Hawthorne's Pizza",
    "type": "Pizza/Italian"
  }, {
    "name": "Luisa's Brick Oven Pizza",
    "type": "Pizza/Italian"
  }, {
    "name": "Maverick Rock Taco",
    "type": "Mexican"
  }, {
    "name": "McAllister's",
    "type": "Sandwiches, Salads, Soups"
  }, {
    "name": "Mellow Mushroom",
    "type": "Pizza/Salads"
  }, {
    "name": "Moe's",
    "type": "Mexican"
  }, {
    "name": "Moosehead Grill",
    "type": "American/Pub "
  }, {
    "name": "Paco's Tacos and Tequila",
    "type": "Mexican"
  }, {
    "name": "Panera ",
    "type": "Sandwiches, Salads, Soups"
  }, {
    "name": "PF Chang's",
    "type": "Chinese"
  }, {
    "name": "Portofinos",
    "type": "Pizza/Italian"
  }, {
    "name": "Qdoba",
    "type": "Mexican"
  }, {
    "name": "Rooster's Wood Fire Kitchen",
    "type": "American/Upscale"
  }, {
    "name": "Rusty's Deli",
    "type": "Sandwiches, Salads, Soups"
  }, {
    "name": "Taco Bell",
    "type": "Fast Food"
  }, {
    "name": "Taco Mac",
    "type": "American/Pub "
  }, {
    "name": "Terrace Café",
    "type": "American/Upscale"
  }, {
    "name": "The Roasting Company",
    "type": "American/Fast"
  }, {
    "name": "Village Tavern",
    "type": "American/Upscale"
  }, {
    "name": "Which Witch?",
    "type": "Sandwiches, Salads, Soups"
  }, {
    "name": "Zack's Hamburgers",
    "type": "American/Fast"
  }];

  // Helpers
  var blackHex = '#333',
    whiteHex = '#fff',
    shuffle = function(o) {
      for (var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x)
      ;
      return o;
    },
    halfPI = Math.PI / 2,
    doublePI = Math.PI * 2;

  String.prototype.hashCode = function() {
    // See http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html        
    var hash = 5381,
      i;
    for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
      char = this.charCodeAt(i);
      hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + char;
      hash = hash & hash; // Convert to 32bit integer
    }
    return hash;
  };

  Number.prototype.mod = function(n) {
    return ((this % n) + n) % n;
  };

  // WHEEL!
  var wheel = {
    timerHandle: 0,
    timerDelay: 33,

    angleCurrent: 0,
    angleDelta: 0,

    size: 290,

    canvasContext: null,

    colors: ['#003366', '#FF6600', '#CCCC00', '#006600', '#3333CC', '#CC0066', '#FF3300', '#009900', '#6600CC', '#33CC33', '#0066CC', '#FF0066', '#3300FF', '#00CC00', '#FFCC00'],

    segments: [],

    seg_colors: [], // Cache of segments to colors

    maxSpeed: Math.PI / 16,

    upTime: 1000, // How long to spin up for (in ms)
    downTime: 5000, // How long to slow down for (in ms)

    spinStart: 0,

    frames: 0,

    centerX: 300,
    centerY: 300,

    spin: function() {
      // Start the wheel only if it's not already spinning
      if (wheel.timerHandle == 0) {
        wheel.spinStart = new Date().getTime();
        wheel.maxSpeed = Math.PI / (16 + Math.random()); // Randomly vary how hard the spin is
        wheel.frames = 0;
        wheel.sound.play();

        wheel.timerHandle = setInterval(wheel.onTimerTick, wheel.timerDelay);
      }
    },

    onTimerTick: function() {
      var duration = (new Date().getTime() - wheel.spinStart),
        progress = 0,
        finished = false;

      wheel.frames++;
      wheel.draw();

      if (duration < wheel.upTime) {
        progress = duration / wheel.upTime;
        wheel.angleDelta = wheel.maxSpeed *
          Math.sin(progress * halfPI);
      } else {
        progress = duration / wheel.downTime;
        wheel.angleDelta = wheel.maxSpeed *
          Math.sin(progress * halfPI + halfPI);
        if (progress >= 1) {
          finished = true;
        }
      }

      wheel.angleCurrent += wheel.angleDelta;
      while (wheel.angleCurrent >= doublePI) {
        // Keep the angle in a reasonable range
        wheel.angleCurrent -= doublePI;
      }
      if (finished) {
        clearInterval(wheel.timerHandle);
        wheel.timerHandle = 0;
        wheel.angleDelta = 0;

        if (console) {
          console.log((wheel.frames / duration * 1000) + " FPS");
        }
      }

      /*
      // Display RPM
      var rpm = (wheel.angleDelta * (1000 / wheel.timerDelay) * 60) / (Math.PI * 2);
      $("#counter").html( Math.round(rpm) + " RPM" );
       */
    },

    init: function(optionList) {
      try {
        wheel.initWheel();
        wheel.initAudio();
        wheel.initCanvas();
        wheel.draw();

        $.extend(wheel, optionList);

      } catch (exceptionData) {
        alert('Wheel is not loaded ' + exceptionData);
      }

    },

    initAudio: function() {
      var sound = document.createElement('audio');
      sound.setAttribute('src', 'wheel.mp3');
      wheel.sound = sound;
    },

    initCanvas: function() {
      var canvas = $('#canvas')[0];
      canvas.addEventListener("click", wheel.spin, false);
      wheel.canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");
    },

    initWheel: function() {
      shuffle(wheel.colors);
    },

    // Called when segments have changed
    update: function() {
      // Ensure we start mid way on a item
      //var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * wheel.segments.length);
      var r = 0,
        segments = wheel.segments,
        len = segments.length,
        colors = wheel.colors,
        colorLen = colors.length,
        seg_color = [], // Generate a color cache (so we have consistant coloring)
        i
      wheel.angleCurrent = ((r + 0.5) / wheel.segments.length) * doublePI;

      for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        seg_color.push(colors[segments[i].hashCode().mod(colorLen)]);
      }
      wheel.seg_color = seg_color;

      wheel.draw();
    },

    draw: function() {
      wheel.clear();
      wheel.drawWheel();
      wheel.drawNeedle();
    },

    clear: function() {
      wheel.canvasContext.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 800);
    },

    drawNeedle: function() {
      var ctx = wheel.canvasContext,
        centerX = wheel.centerX,
        centerY = wheel.centerY,
        size = wheel.size,
        i,
        centerSize = centerX + size,
        len = wheel.segments.length,
        winner;

      ctx.lineWidth = 2;
      ctx.strokeStyle = blackHex;
      ctx.fillStyle = whiteHex;

      ctx.beginPath();

      ctx.moveTo(centerSize - 10, centerY);
      ctx.lineTo(centerSize + 10, centerY - 10);
      ctx.lineTo(centerSize + 10, centerY + 10);
      ctx.closePath();

      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.fill();

      // Which segment is being pointed to?
      i = len - Math.floor((wheel.angleCurrent / doublePI) * len) - 1;

      // Now draw the winning name
      ctx.textAlign = "left";
      ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
      ctx.fillStyle = '#fff000'
      ctx.font = "5em Arial";
      winner = wheel.segments[i] || 'Choose at least 1 Venue';
      ctx.fillText(winner, centerSize + 20, centerY);
    },

    drawSegment: function(key, lastAngle, angle) {
      var ctx = wheel.canvasContext,
        centerX = wheel.centerX,
        centerY = wheel.centerY,
        size = wheel.size,
        colors = wheel.seg_color,
        value = wheel.segments[key];

      //ctx.save();
      ctx.beginPath();

      // Start in the centre
      ctx.moveTo(centerX, centerY);
      ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, size, lastAngle, angle, false); // Draw an arc around the edge
      ctx.lineTo(centerX, centerY); // Now draw a line back to the center

      // Clip anything that follows to this area
      //ctx.clip(); // It would be best to clip, but we can double performance without it
      ctx.closePath();

      ctx.fillStyle = colors[key];
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();

      // Now draw the text
      ctx.save(); // The save ensures this works on Android devices
      ctx.translate(centerX, centerY);
      ctx.rotate((lastAngle + angle) / 2);

      ctx.fillStyle = whiteHex;
      ctx.fillText(value.substr(0, 20), size - 15, 0);
      ctx.restore();
    },

    drawWheel: function() {
      var ctx = wheel.canvasContext,
        angleCurrent = wheel.angleCurrent,
        lastAngle = angleCurrent,
        len = wheel.segments.length,
        centerX = wheel.centerX,
        centerY = wheel.centerY,
        size = wheel.size,
        angle,
        i;

      ctx.lineWidth = 1;
      ctx.strokeStyle = blackHex;
      ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
      ctx.textAlign = "right";
      ctx.font = "1em Arial";

      for (i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
        angle = doublePI * (i / len) + angleCurrent;
        wheel.drawSegment(i - 1, lastAngle, angle);
        lastAngle = angle;
      }

      // Draw a center circle
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, 20, 0, doublePI, false);
      ctx.closePath();

      ctx.fillStyle = whiteHex;
      //ctx.strokeStyle = blackHex;
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();

      // Draw outer circle
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, size, 0, doublePI, false);
      ctx.closePath();

      ctx.lineWidth = 10;
      //ctx.strokeStyle = blackHex;
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  };
  $(function() {
    var $venues = $('#venues'),
      $venueName = $('#name'),
      $venueType = $('#types'),
      venueTypes = [],
      $list = $('<ul/>'),
      $types = $('<ul/>'),
      $filterToggler = $('#filterToggle'),
      arrayUnique = function(a) {
        return a.reduce(function(p, c) {
          if (p.indexOf(c) < 0) {
            p.push(c);
          }
          return p;
        }, []);
      };

    $.each(venues, function(index, venue) {
      $list.append(
        $("<li/>")
        .append(
          $("<input />").attr({
            id: 'venue-' + index,
            name: venue.name,
            value: venue.name,
            type: 'checkbox',
            checked: true
          })
          .change(function() {
            var cbox = this,
              segments = wheel.segments,
              i = segments.indexOf(cbox.value);

            if (cbox.checked && i === -1) {
              segments.push(cbox.value);
            } else if (!cbox.checked && i !== -1) {
              segments.splice(i, 1);
            }

            segments.sort();
            wheel.update();
          })

        ).append(
          $('<label />').attr({
            'for': 'venue-' + index
          })
          .text(venue.name)
        )
      );
      venueTypes.push(venue.type);
    });
    $.each(arrayUnique(venueTypes), function(index, venue) {
      $types.append(
        $("<li/>")
        .append(
          $("<input />").attr({
            id: 'venue-type-' + index,
            name: venue,
            value: venue,
            type: 'checkbox',
            checked: true
          })
          .change(function() {
            var $this = $(this),
              i;
            for (i = 0; i < venues.length; i++) {
              if (venues[i].type === $this.val()) {
                $('[name="' + venues[i].name + '"]').prop("checked", $this.prop('checked')).trigger('change');
              }
            }
          })

        ).append(
          $('<label />').attr({
            'for': 'venue-' + index
          })
          .text(venue)
        )
      )
    });

    $venueName.append($list);
    $venueType.append($types);
    // Uses the tinysort plugin, but our array is sorted for now.
    //$list.find('>li').tsort("input", {attr: "value"});

    wheel.init();

    $.each($venueName.find('ul input:checked'), function(key, cbox) {
      wheel.segments.push(cbox.value);
    });

    wheel.update();
    $venues.slideUp().data("open", false);
    $filterToggler.on("click", function() {
      if ($venues.data("open")) {
        $venues.slideUp().data("open", false);
      } else {
        $venues.slideDown().data("open", true);
      }
    });

    $('.checkAll').on("click", function() {
      $(this).parent().next('div').find('input').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked')).trigger("change");
    });
  });
}(jQuery));
```

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #666;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 2;
}

input[type='checkbox']+label {
  padding-left: .5em;
}

label,
#filterToggle {
  display: inline-block;
}

#venues,
#filterToggle {
  background: #fefefe;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #efefef;
}

#venues {
  padding: .5em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#venues ul,
#venues h2 {
  clear: both;
}

#venues li {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  line-height: 1.5;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#filterToggle {
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: .5em;
  margin-top: -1px;
  padding: .5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="venues">
  <h1>Venues <input type="checkbox" class="checkAll" checked /></h1>
  <div id="name"></div>
  <h2>Types <input type="checkbox" class="checkAll" checked /></h2>
  <div id="types"></div>
</div>
<div id="filterToggle">. . .</div>
<div id="wheel">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="600"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="counter"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, why did the width of the viewability of text got reduced?

Comment: You will have to play with the other widths too. I have never used this library, just read your code and played a little with it.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it. I want add `<br>` to break the text to new line as well.